# Why does using tarfile.extract() result in error: no attribute 'extract'?

Tags: python, tarfile

I'm using Python 3.4. 
Writing

```
csv_f = tarfile.open('C:\\Users\\somefile.gz')
```

works fine but this

```
csv_f = tarfile.extract('C:\\Users\\somefile.gz')
```

causes the response

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'extract'
```

It seems the extract and extractall functions aren't being found in the library. How can that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they're methods of the object returned by `tarfile.open()`, not functions in the module itself.

Comment: Thanks! How do I use the correct syntax in tar file to extract the file?

Comment: Just like the documentation says, you pass it the member to extract.